# How to find the hyperbolic angle given the mean anomaly?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, gravity-assist, calculation

I'm modelling a hyperbolic gravity assist trajectory around Jupiter and trying to calculate the coordinates for each hour interval before/after passing periapsis.
I've calculated $M_h = 0.0176$ is the mean anomaly 1 hour from periapsis, but how can I determine the corresponding hyperbolic angle, i.e solve this equation for H, given e = 1.3893:

$$M_h = 0.0176 = e~\rm sinh\it(H) - H$$

Using iterative calculations I know the answer is approximately $H = 0.04$, but I'm hoping to solve the equation above "precisely".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like the corresponding [eccentric anomaly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eccentric_anomaly) for elliptical  orbits, there is no closed-form formula for going from [mean anomaly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_anomaly) to [hyperbolic anomaly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_trajectory#Equations_of_motion).

You're going to have to use some sort of numerical method to go in that direction. [Newton-Raphson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) tends to converge quickly enough.

$${\displaystyle x_{n+1}=x_{n}-{\frac {f(x_{n})}{f'(x_{n})}}}$$

With Mean anomaly at the chosen time as $M$, we'll look for zeroes on the function:
$$f(H_n) = e \sinh H_n - H_n -M $$
And we'll need its first derivative:
$$f'(H_n) = e \cosh H_n - 1$$

And we'll iterate with:

$$H_{n+1} = H_n - \frac{e \sinh H_n - H_n -M}{e \cosh H_n -1}$$

In almost every case I've used it, it's been useful to set the initial guess of the hyperbolic anomaly $H_0$ equal to the Mean Anomaly $M$. Given your chosen parameters of eccentricity $e = 1.3893$ and mean anomaly $M = 0.0176$, these are the values pulled up from a quick Google Sheets Spreadsheet:

| Iteration | Hyperbolic Anomaly |
| --- | --- |
| $H_0$ | $\underline{0.0}176$ |
| $H_1$ | $\underline{0.0451}9085695$ |
| $H_2$ | $\underline{0.045154584}33$ |
| $H_3$ | $\underline{0.04515458422}$ |
| ... | ... |

Newton-Raphson's convergence is typically quadratic, resulting in roughly doubling the number of correct digits each iteration. We're at the three significant figures of your mean anomaly value by $H_1$, and by $H_3$ the iterated value doesn't change under the floating-point precision Google Sheets can handle.

One more thing: The convergence of using the Newton-Raphson method above with Kepler's equations gets slower as orbital eccentricity approaches $e=1$. If Orbital eccentricity was $e=1.01$, it would take until $H_7$ to get three significant figures stable from the specified Mean Anomaly. At $e=1.001, H_{21}$, and $e=1.0001, H_{74}$, and so forth. If your hyperbolas are extremely near-parabolic, you may need to look into an alternate method to calculate position as a function of time.